# Polymorphic association with different names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have three rails 4 models: `Chapters`, `Sections`, `Videos`. Each `Chapter` has a single `introductory_video` and each `Section` can have many `videos`.

From what I can gather, I will need to use a polymorphic association, but I'm not sure how to model it correctly. Here is my code so far:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :videoable, polymorphic: true
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, as: :videoable
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, as: :videoable
end
```

Is it possible to achieve this or should I break `IntroductoryVideos` into a separate model class?

Comment: I think the way you have it will work, but I think you want Chapter to has_one :video, as: :videoable

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to achive it like this. Just change:

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, as: :videoable
end
```

to

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :video, as: :videoable
end
```

The rest is